# LibGDX Android: nothing to see on loading screen (render method does not draw)

Tags: android, graphics, libgdx

When I launch my application on *Android*, nothing is being shown on the loading screen, it is just black.

That screen is supposed to be shown while some assets are loading when you start the application.

Everything works fine in the *Desktop* application.
How to make the loading screen show on *Android*?

**I do the following in `show()` of the loading screen:**

```
Assets.load();    //assets are being loaded there

cam = new OrthographicCamera();
viewport = new StretchViewport(width, height, cam);
viewport.apply();
cam.position.set(cam.viewportWidth / 2, cam.viewportHeight / 2, 0);
cam.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

sprite = new Sprite(new Texture(texturePath));
sprite.setPosition(100, 200);
```

**I do the following in `render()` of the loading screen:**

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(.17f, .17f, .25f, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

cam.update();
batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

batch.begin();
sprite.draw(batch);
batch.end();

if(Assets.manager.update())
    game.setScreen(nextScreen);
```

Comment: and there is no errors in logs, right?

Comment: No, I don't find any errors there. And I know that the screen's `render()` method is being called, but somehow there is no drawing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to make it work:
make another empty screen show up before the loading screen.

I really don't understand why that works, but I hope this will help someone.
(If you know what part of that made it work, then it would be nice if you help:D)

**Part of my empty screen:**

```
public class EmptyScreen implements Screen {

OrthographicCamera cam;
Viewport viewport;
SpriteBatch batch;
MyGame game;

public EmptyScreen(SpriteBatch batch, MyGame game) {
    this.game = game;
    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport = new StretchViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), cam);
    viewport.apply();

    this.batch = batch;
}

@Override
public void show() {

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    game.setScreen(new LoadingScreen(game, batch));
}
```

**Part of my (now working on android as well) loading screen**

```
public class LoadingScreen implements Screen {

MyGame game;
Sprite sprite;
OrthographicCamera cam;
Viewport viewport;
Stage stage;
SpriteBatch batch;

public LoadingScreen(MyGame game, SpriteBatch batch) {
    this.game = game;
    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport = new StretchViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), cam);
    viewport.apply();

    cam.position.set(cam.viewportWidth / 2, cam.viewportHeight / 2, 0);

    this.batch = batch;

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

    sprite = new Sprite(new Texture(texturePath));
    //you may need to set the position of the sprite here
}

@Override
public void show() {
    stage = new Stage(viewport, batch);
    Assets.load();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(.1f, .2f, .25f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);  

    batch.begin();
    sprite.draw(batch);  
    batch.end();

    if(Assets.manager.update())
        game.setScreen(nextScreen);
    }
```